# Understanding call() Function and Objects

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, prototype

I have a modular JS project that I was given to tweak. It uses prototype inheritance as opposed to classes. Here is the code in question:

Constructor in hgManager.js:

```
export function HGManager() {
    this.USER_ID = getURLParameter( "usr" ),
    this.GAME_ID = getURLParameter( "game" )
};
```

getData() in hgManager.js:

```
getData: function(a, b) {
        var c = this.API + "records/" + this.USER_ID + "/" + this.GAME_ID;
        this.xhrLoad( "GET", c, a, b )
    },
```

xhrLoad() in hgManager.js:

```
xhrLoad: function(a, b, c, d, e) {

        var f = new XMLHttpRequest;
        f.open(a, b, true), 
        e && f.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        var g = this;

        f.onload = function() {
            if (4 == f.readyState && f.status >= 400 && f.status <= 599) {                     return d.call(g, f);
            }

            else { 
                var a = JSON.parse( f.responseText ).response;

                return c.call(g, a, f)    
            }

        },

        f.onerror = function() {
            return d.call(g, f)
        },


        e ? f.send( JSON.stringify( e ) ) : f.send() 
    }
```

A function that calls hgManager.getData():

```
loadPlayerData: function() { 
        var a = this;
        this.game.hgManager.getData(
            function( c ) { //param 1
                if ( null === c ) { 
                    return void console.log( "DataManager: Invalid response." ); //if there is no playerData
                }

                var d = JSON.parse( c.record );
                void 0 === d || null === d || void 0 === d.selectedCharacter ? (console.log("DataManager: No data on backend, looking for data on local storage."), d = a._getLocalStorageData(), null !== d ? (console.log("DataManager: Data on localstorage found. Saving this to backend."), a.game.playerData = d) : console.log("DataManager: No data on localstorage. Saving default data to backend."), a.savePlayerData()) : console.log("DataManager: Data loaded from backend.");
                var e = new Date,
                    f = e.getFullYear() + "-" + e.getMonth();
                d.lastMonthPlayed != f && (d.lastMonthPlayed = f, d.loyaltyPoints = [], console.log("DataManager: New month, reset loyalty points.")),
                a.game.playerData = d,
                a.game.hasShownLoyaltyMessage = a.game.playerData.loyaltyPoints.length > 0,
                a.game.hasShownPortalMessage = 9 == a.game.playerData.portalPieces.length
            },

            function() { //param 2
                console.log("DataManager: Error loading user data"), 
                data = a._getLocalStorageData(), 
                null !== data ? (console.log("DataManager: Data on localstorage found."), a.game.playerData = data) : console.log("DataManager: No data on localstorage.") 
            }
        ) 
    },
```

The code that is throwing me off is `return c.call(g, a, f)` in `xhrLoad()`, and the corresponding first parameter function of `loadPlayerData()`.

- Where does the parameter 'c' in `this.game.hgManager.getData(function( c ) {` come from? It is clearly not defined in this scope, so I imagine it is a result of the `call()`?
- How does `loadPlayerData()` read what appears to be undefined in the scope?
- Given the function `this.game.hgManager.getData( function(c)`, why would we reassign the parent object and call `getData()`? What is the intent?

Comment: This is too broad a question. Try doing some research on [callback functions in Javascript](https://www.google.cl/search?q=callback+functions+in+javascript)

Comment: The parameter `c` in `function( c )` is defined right there, between the parentheses. What you're doing there is you're passing a function as a parameter to another function -- this is called a *callback*. The two functions you pass to `getData` tell it what to do when the data has been successfully loaded, or when an error has occurred, respectively. `loadPlayerData` doesn't read the value of `c`, because it's not executing those functions, just defining them so they can be called later.

Comment: Also, for the record: *all* JavaScript code uses prototype inheritance; the concept of classes doesn't really exist in this language (the `class` declaration is just syntactic sugar). I'd suggest reading up on MDN about functions and objects in JavaScript, they work very differently from many other languages.

Comment: @MátéSafranka `console.log( c )` returns a Player Data object, despite not being explicitly defined. Is this also part of the callback concept? I am confused because it feels like `c` came out of thin air and somehow works just as needed.

Comment: `c` is just a function parameter like you would use in any other function, i.e. it receives its value when it's called. In this case, you define the callback function, you pass it to `getData`, and then at some point, that function is called, and a `PlayerData` object is passed to it as an argument.

Comment: It's really not as complicated as it sound, it's just that you're looking at a very complex example right now. I'd recommend you read up on callbacks and then play around with very short, simple bits of code you write yourself to see how it works. For example: `var dbl = function(n) { return n * 2; }; var print = function(f) { var x = 15; var y = f(x); console.log(x, y); }; print(dbl);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite difficult to deal with variables like `a, b, c` especially when they mean different things in different scopes.

But let's try to follow code and rename args to add some sence:

```
xhrLoad: function(method, target, callbackSuccess, callbackError, e/* idk what is it*/) {}

getData: function(callbackSuccess, callbackError) {
        var target = this.API + "records/" + this.USER_ID + "/" + this.GAME_ID;
        this.xhrLoad( "GET", target, callbackSuccess, callbackError )
    },

this.game.hgManager.getData(
        function( response ) { //param 1 callbackSucess
                if ( null === response ) { 
                    return void console.log( "DataManager: Invalid response." ); //if there is no playerData
                }


            },
        function() { //param 2 callbackError
          //
        }
```

Now it's easier to understand.

`getData()` accepts as arguments two callback functions - one for successful response and one for error. First one must accept response as argument. It's your `c` from `this.game.hgManager.getData(function( c ) {` and it's defined right here. Since it's a function's argument, there is no need to define it in global scope.

And seems, that there is nothing to do with classes here. It's all about passing functions as arguments.